# Lightning Experience - How to get the Alpha Rolodex on Search Pages?

Tags: account, lightning-experience

The Alphabet Ribbon/Rolodex that appeared at the top right corner of specifically the account listing is no longer available in the new Lightning Experience.  Is it simply disabled or not part of the new experience?

Answer (score 4):

It's not there as part of Lightning Experience. It is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_migration_whatsnew/lex_migration_whatsnew_more).

> Navigation through list views has changed. Because list views have
>   infinite scrolling, you can’t specify the number of records to show
>   per page. Also, you can’t navigate through pages with arrow buttons,
>   and you can’t jump to a specific page of results. **There’s no alphabet
>   rolodex for list views.**

This is also documented in the [Lightning Experience Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/lightning_experience_guide.pdf).

> Limitations and Differences
>
> Some features and links that are available on object home pages in
>   Salesforce Classic aren’t available on comparable pages in Lightning
>   Experience. Here are a few examples. The rest can be found in
>   Lightning Experience Considerations.
>
> **• Navigation through list views has changed. Because list views have infinite scrolling, you can’t specify the number of records to show
>   per page. Also, you can’t navigate through pages with arrow buttons,
>   and you can’t jump to a specific page of results. There’s no alphabet
>   rolodex for list views.**
>
> • Your users can reorder the columns of the Recently Viewed Object
>   list in Salesforce Classic and the changes are reflected in Lightning
>   Experience.
>
> • Custom buttons and custom actions aren’t supported for list views or
>   list view items.